# Is there a way to highlight searches done with grepprg?

Tags: search, the-silver-searcher

I'm using [vim-grepper](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-grepper) plugin, but I guess it doesn't really matter.
What I want is when I'm searching for something inside my project via vim-grepper or some grepprg if there are matches inside opened files they would be highlighted as if I was searched for them with `/some search`.

Comment: The only real way to fix that is to have the external utility print out the location of the matches (line number, start column, end column) and then use `matchaddpos()` to add matches for that. For example the [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/autoload/go/guru.vim#L363) plugin uses this for some commands.

Comment: It's seems to be possible to get match line and columns from Ag. I'll read about matchaddpos, thanks

Comment: `matchaddpos()` is not exactly the most user-friendly function in Vim.  Ask the authors of `vim-grepper` to add highlighting, or switch to a plugin that already does that, f.i. [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) (`CtrlSF` doesn't take as many sources as `vim-grepper` though).